# Can sbrk(2) or mmap(2) block?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

As the title says, can sbrk(2) or mmap(2) block? As in, can they sleep, or do anything else that yields to the scheduler?

Comment: Any syscall can block, otherwise `EINTR` would not exist, right?

Comment: I believe they can block, e.g. if they require memory and there is a need for a page swap out to make some memory available. May I ask _why_ you are asking this? Is it out of curiosity or are you going to rely on this behavior? In the later case, you would be doing something really wrong!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But then, the man makes no mention of `EINTR` for [sbrk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) or [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), while it does for others like [write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html).

Comment: @Shahbaz Mainly out of curiosity. Seeing if what I think is right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can.

sbrk() on modern systems is very similar to mmap(), so they can be discussed as one entity.

And mmap() can block, because setting up a user visible virtual memory mapping requires a relatively complex data structure setup on the kernel side, which involves kernel allocating memory from its internal allocators (such as kmem_cache_alloc(), which can block unless requested not to).

In-kernel code has support for non-blocking memory mapping, but it is only used in special cases, because it is impossible to ensure that such mapping will always succeed. On recent enough linux system this behavior can be explicitly requested from user space with MAP_NONBLOCK flag to mmap() call (be prepared to deal with mapping failures).